# From general parametrization to parametrisation as function

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\gamma$  be a clesed curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ given by
$$\begin{array}{ccl}
                              \gamma : [a,b] & \longrightarrow &\mathbb{R^2} \\
                              t    & \longmapsto & \gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t)).
                            \end{array}$$
locally we can parametrise the curve $\gamma$ as a graph of function $(t,f(t))$

My question is how we can express $f(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If $x(t)$ is invertible on some interval $I\subset[a,b]$, then for all $t\in x(I)$ the point $(t,y(x^{-1}(t)))$ is on $\gamma$ and all points of $\gamma$ where $x(t)\in x(I)$ can be written in this form. Thus for $t\in x(I)$ one should define:
$$f(t)=y(x^{-1}(t)).$$

Comment: thank you @Peter Melech for this nice response. what if $x(t)$is not invertible ?

Comment: Of course this is just an idea for the case if $x(t)$ is locally invertible, if there is no such interval on which $x(t)$ is invertible it doesn't work. In this sense this is no complete answer, I apologize